# Bus error: 10 using gulp watch, foundation, & sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I'm running several gulp tasks using

```
gulp watch
```

and after they've completed, before the watch begins  - receiving a

```
Bus error: 10
```

error which crashes gulp watch.  This is after gulp seemingly has completed all of the queued tasks.

Any ideas?

I've seen answers around specific versions of node ~v0.10.x but I'm running v0.12.2 - so not looking for a pointer to one of those threads.

Comment: If Node dies with a SIGBUS that's basically a Node bug. (or I guess a bug in some native-code extension)

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce a problem.  Did you try slimming down your file to verify exactly which process is causing the crash?

Comment: There may not be enough info to reproduce it at random, but when I encountered this problem and found this question I was able to resolve my issue according to the recommended answer. I wish that Bus 10 was actually replaced with something more telling, like, "dude, you have a circular reference somewhere".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure you're not including a circular reference in one of your mixins.

I ran into this issue when I accidentally included something like this:

```
@mixin some_mixin(){ 
  .element {
    @include some_mixin();
  }
}
```

If you have an @include within it's own mixin definition, it will throw that error.

Comment: Unless the problem is clearly identifiable/reproducible from what is provided in the question, it is best to refrain from asking until such information becomes available.  For all you know, the problem might not be with Sass at all.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. While it wasn't exactly including a mixin from within a mixin, I had _pg.scss which was importing '_pg', so it was still a circular reference.

Comment: This also helped. My issue was that I accidentally added `@import` into the same file that it was referencing! Doh!